# Why did Ashur face Spartacus's gladiator army alone?

Tags: character, spartacus-tv

Why did Ashur take such a foolish risk facing Spartacus's army all alone, resulting in his death at the hands of Naevia? It should have been so easy for him to run away. Why follow Glaber's commands and risk his own life when Nobody was watching him?

He had shown himself to be a clever and selfish person up to this point, yet he acted so stupidly in this case. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ashur had a chip on his shoulder by not being accepted as a true gladiator. Recall he once went back into training once he recovered from his early disabling fight, but his owner told him to get back to his secretarial duties. So, he always felt belittled by the other gladiators. I assume this last stand was his effort to demonstrate that he could be one of the true gladiators by facing them in battle.